# Using setTimeout with snap.svg

Tags: html, svg, snap.svg

I've loaded an external [svg](/questions/tagged/svg)file using [snap.svg](/questions/tagged/snap.svg)and want a certain part (`id="city_whole"`) of it to appear 3 sec after page loading with fade in animation.

Simplified Markup:

```
<body style="height:100%;overflow:hidden">
    <div class="viewport show home" id="home">
    <svg id="svg" ></svg>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my Document ready function:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
s.attr({
  viewBox: [0, 0, 1200, 600]
});

Snap.load("shilp6.svg", function(f) {
  var city_w = f.select('#city_whole');
  setTimeout(function() {
    city_w.animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 3000, mina.backout)
  }, 3000);
  //setTimeout(svg_appear, 3000);
  //function svg_appear() {
  //    city_w.animate({opacity: 1},3000,mina.backout);
  //}
  s.append(f.select("#city_whole"));
});
```

I also tried doing it other way (shown above in commented part) but it also didn't worked.I am not able to figure out what am i doing wrong. Somebody please help or suggest any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

You need to use:

```
var city_w = Snap('#city_whole');
```

Example:

```js
var s = Snap("#svg");
s.attr({
  viewBox: [0, 0, 1200, 600]
});
Snap.load("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg", function(f) {
  s.append(f); // First: add the external svg image in the DOM.
  
  var city_w = Snap('#path119');
  setTimeout(function() {
    city_w.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 3000, mina.backout);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://snapsvg.io/assets/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></svg>
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/k3zp3dva/2/

Comment: After using `var city_w = Snap('#city_whole');` I am getting console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'animate' of null` and it still isn't working .

Comment: If #city_whole exists in the DOM then Snap("#city_whole") will return an object with proper context to manipulate the properties of #city_whole.

In your case, #city_whole doesn't exist. Make sure #city_whole is already created.

Try inspecting the DOM of your svg when is finally builded in the page.

Comment: I think #city_whole does exist in DOM because when i use `var s = Snap("#svg");
s.attr({
    viewBox: [0, 0, 1200, 600]
});

Snap.load("shilp6.svg", function (f) {
    var city_w = f.select('#city_whole');svg_appear();
    function svg_appear() {
    city_w.animate({opacity: 1},3000,mina.backout);
    }
    s.append(f.select("#city_whole"));
});` i am able to get ease in animation (without the delay)

Comment: If you want #city_whole appear in visible after three seconds, #city_whole must initially be in style = "opacity: 0;".

Your function makes the transition from opacity: 0 to opacity: 1 (100% visible).

I have updated my answer.